# How to request data from hundreds of URLs in Python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using a rest API to pull some data.

I have a list of ~10k urls I can ping to get the data we need.

So, this code works:

```
results = {}

for url in urls:
   results[url] = requests.get(url).json()
```

However, the latency of any given request is ~250ms, so this takes a long time. Seems to me these calls could be done asynchronously.

I use Jupyter Notebooks, so looking for something that works in that context.

UPDATE:

I tried:

```
results = {}
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        results[url] = s.get(url).json()
```

And got a 4x speedup

I also tried:

```
import aiohttp

_results = []

async def get_data(urls:list[str]=urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            r = await session.get(url)
            _result.append(await r.json())

await get_data()
```

But this was not any faster.

I also tried

```
_results = []
def get_data():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for url, response in zip(urls, executor.map(requests.get, urls)):
            _results.append(response.json())

get_data()
```

And it was 3x faster than the previous best (ie. 12x faster than a naive loop)

Comment: Look into threading, though be careful of rate limiting. Also I'm not sure of jupyter but this seems like it'd be a pretty easy question to google.

Comment: Use processpoolexecutors and parallelize your calls ?

Comment: Looks like a job for [`thread pool executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example)

Comment: Please take a look at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804).

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Daewo is a good point. Also, I suggest you to use coroutines over processes because coroutines use less system resources and also the context switch cost is very much lower than between processes.

You used `aiohttp` but your code is no making use of concurrency making the requests. In the next code `asyncio.gather` executes concurrently the requests. When a request is waiting for latency, the other take place to complete.

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get_json(url, session):
    r = await session.get(url)
    return await r.json()

async def get_data(urls:list[str]=urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        return await asyncio.gather(*[
            get_json(url, session)
            for url in urls
        ])

_results = asyncio.run(get_data())
```

Check the documentation for [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

Answer (score 1):

I have created a package called [unparallel](https://github.com/RafaelWO/unparallel) that fits your use case. You can use it as follows:

```py
import asyncio

from unparallel import up


async def main():
    urls = [
        # Add your URLs here
    ]

    # Do GET requests and return `.json()` for all URLs
    responses = await up(urls)

    # Iterate over the data and do something with it
    for url, data in zip(urls[:10], responses):
        print(url, data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

> I have a list of ~10k urls I can ping to get the data we need.

As you have a ton of URLs, the code above will likely raise timeout errors. You probably want to [increase the timeout and the maximum connections](https://rafaelwo.github.io/unparallel/latest/usage/#configuring-limits-and-timeouts) to get it to work.

You can check the [docs](https://rafaelwo.github.io/unparallel/latest/usage/) to find out more about how to parametrize `up()`.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would try is using [Session](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects) as

> if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP
> connection will be reused, which can result in a significant
> performance increase

it could be effortlessly used via `with` in your case it would be

```
results = {}
with requests.Session() as s:
    for url in urls:
        results[url] = s.get(url).json()
```

If this would not provide fast enough solution or you just elect to use *calls done asynchronously* then I suggest trying [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) though I do not know if it will out-of-the-box coexist peacefully with *Jupyter Notebooks*

Comment: Thank you. This gave me a 4x speedup, but it's still slow - I'll try aiohttp.