# Is having a concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor call dangerous in a FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, concurrent.futures, asgi

I have the following test code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
        'http://www.cnn.com/',
        'http://europe.wsj.com/',
        'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

# Retrieve a single page and report the URL and contents
def load_url(url, timeout):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=timeout) as conn:
        return conn.read()

# We can use a with statement to ensure threads are cleaned up promptly
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    # Start the load operations and mark each future with its URL
    future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
        url = future_to_url[future]
        try:
            data = future.result()
        except Exception as exc:
            print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
        else:
            print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

I need to use the `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` part of the code in a FastAPI endpoint.

My concern is the impact of the number of API calls and the inclusion of threads. Concern about creating too many threads and its related consequences, starving the host, crashing the application and/or the host.

Any thoughts or gotchas on this approach?

Comment: I share your concerns about creating too many threads. If what you want to do is a lot of network requests, I would recommend looking into async (using e.g. [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) and `asyncio.gather()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way to make downstream Https requests inside of Uvicorn/FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721736/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-downstream-https-requests-inside-of-uvicorn-fasta)

Comment: Do you need to perform requests for all five URLs each time a user makes an API call?

Comment: @chris yes I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use the [`HTTPX`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) library, which [provides an `async` API](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/). As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) , you spawn a `Client` and reuse it every time you need it. To make [asynchronous requests with `HTTPX`](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#making-async-requests), you'll need an [`AsyncClient`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/71ee50b27770b461a5d2aaba9fca1fbc261bede1/httpx/_client.py#L1297).

You could control the connection pool size as well, using the `limits` keyword argument on the `Client`, which takes an instance of [`httpx.Limits`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/9e97d7d42963e408ef2949cc86515d6025dbec24/httpx/_config.py#L276). For example:

```py
limits = httpx.Limits(max_keepalive_connections=5, max_connections=10)
client = httpx.AsyncClient(limits=limits)
```

You can adjust the above per your needs. As per the documentation on [Pool limit configuration](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#pool-limit-configuration):

> - `max_keepalive_connections`, number of allowable keep-alive    connections, or `None` to always allow. (Defaults **20**)
> - `max_connections`, maximum number of allowable connections, or `None`    for no limits. (Default **100**)
> - `keepalive_expiry`, time limit on idle keep-alive connections in    seconds, or `None` for no limits. (Default **5**)

If you would like to [adjust the timeout](https://www.python-httpx.org/advanced/#timeout-configuration) as well, you can use the `timeout` paramter to set timeout on an individual request, or on a `Client`/`AsyncClient` instance, which results in the given timeout being used as the default for requests made with this client (see the implementation of [`Timeout`](https://github.com/encode/httpx/blob/9baf3a6cd2fa9ebeb17dba5a3e5c6e9e0af83a96/httpx/_config.py#L189) class as well). You can specify the timeout behavior in a fine grained detail; for example, setting the `read` timeout parameter will specify the maximum duration to wait for a chunk of data to be received (i.e., a chunk of the response body). If `HTTPX` is unable to receive data within this time frame, a `ReadTimeout` exception is raised. If set to `None` instead of some positive numerical value, there will be no `timeout` on `read`. The default is 5 seconds `timeout` on all operations.

You can use `await client.aclose()` to [explicitly close the `AsyncClient`](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#opening-and-closing-clients) when you are done with it (this could be done inside a [shutdown event](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#shutdown-event) handler, for instance).

To **run multiple asynchronous operations**—as you need to request five different URLs, when your API endpoint is called—you can use the *awaitable* [`asyncio.gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather). It will execute the `async` operations and return a list of results in the same order the [awaitables](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#awaitables) (`tasks`) were passed to that function.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import httpx
import asyncio


URLS = ['https://www.foxnews.com/',
        'https://edition.cnn.com/',
        'https://www.nbcnews.com/',
        'https://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'https://www.reuters.com/']


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # customise settings
    limits = httpx.Limits(max_keepalive_connections=5, max_connections=10)
    timeout = httpx.Timeout(5.0, read=15.0)  # 15s timeout on read. 5s timeout elsewhere.

    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(limits=limits, timeout=timeout) as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def send(url, client):
    return await client.get(url)


@app.get('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    tasks = [send(url, client) for url in URLS]
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return [r.text[:50] for r in responses]  # for demo purposes, only return the first 50 chars of each response
```

If you would like to **avoid reading the entire responses' body into RAM**, you could use [Streaming responses](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/#streaming-responses) in `httpx`, as well as utilise FastAPI's `StreamingResponse`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73770074/17865804) and demonstrated below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
import httpx
import asyncio


URLS = ['https://www.foxnews.com/',
        'https://edition.cnn.com/',
        'https://www.nbcnews.com/',
        'https://www.bbc.co.uk/',
        'https://www.reuters.com/']


@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    # customise settings
    limits = httpx.Limits(max_keepalive_connections=5, max_connections=10)
    timeout = httpx.Timeout(5.0, read=15.0)  # 15s timeout on read. 5s timeout elsewhere.

    # Initialise the Client on startup and add it to the state
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(limits=limits, timeout=timeout) as client:
        yield {'client': client}
        # The Client closes on shutdown 


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


async def send(url, client):
    req = client.build_request('GET', url)
    return await client.send(req, stream=True)


async def iter_content(responses):
     for r in responses:
        async for chunk in r.aiter_text():
            yield chunk[:50]  # for demo purposes, only return the first 50 chars of each response
            yield '\n\n'
            break
        await r.aclose()


@app.get('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    client = request.state.client
    tasks = [send(url, client) for url in URLS]
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return StreamingResponse(iter_content(responses), media_type='text/event-stream')
```