# Azure Web App returns Internal Error Server when executing a Get Request using FastAPI in Python code

Tags: fastapi, internal-server-error, python-requests-html, azure-webapps

We are trying to execute a Get Request from the Azure Web App using our python code. The request will be made to our DevOps Repo following the available API. This is just a part (example) of the entire code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import requests
import base64
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"Hello": "Pycharm"}

@app.get('/file')
async def sqlcode(p: str = '/ppppppppp',
            v: str = 'vvvv',
            r: str = 'rrrrrr',
            pn: str = 'nnnnnnn'):
    organizational_url = f'https://xxxxxxxx/{pn}/_apis/git/repositories/{r}/items?path={p}&versionDescriptor.version={v}&api-version=6.1-preview.1'
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    basic_authentication = base64.b64encode((f'{username}:{password}').encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Basic {basic_authentication}',
    }
    response = requests.get(url=organizational_url, headers=headers) 
    return {"sqlcode": response.text}


# Code ends for Fastapi with swagger
def print_hi(name):
    print(f'Hi, {name}')  # Press Ctrl+F8 to toggle the breakpoint.

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_hi('PyCharm')
```

And this is the requirements.txt

```
Flask==2.0.1
asyncpg==0.21.0
databases==0.4.1
fastapi==0.63.0
gunicorn==20.0.4
pydantic==1.7.3
SQLAlchemy==1.3.22
uvicorn==0.11.5
config==0.3.9
pandas==1.5.3
dask==2023.1.0
azure.storage.blob==12.14.1
pysftp==0.2.9
azure-identity==1.12.0
azure-keyvault-secrets==4.6.0
```

When we execute the code in Pycharm this works without any issue :

[image]

But when we execute the same code from the Web App we've got the **Internal Server Error Message**

[image]

I'm just trying to help the team to understand this error. I'm not a cloud engineer. What could be missing, is it something in the code, a particular port to use, is a permission needed in Azure Web Service?

Comment: Can you get the application logs from azure? There should be a python error there.

Comment: Hi That is the thing. The logs does not show nothing, and unfortunately we do not have manager permission.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) on how to issue HTTP requests inside FastAPI `async def` endpoints.