# Download file from CDN/FTP server FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

Hi all im new to FastAPI and im looking for a way to save excel files that are hosted on some server.

What I have currently is something like this and I can use that in FastApi function but I don't think that this is the best way to handle this.

```py
import shutil
import urllib.request
from contextlib import closing

with closing(urllib.request.urlopen('ftp://server/path/to/file')) as r:
    with open('file', 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)
```

What i want to do is to pass some URL that leads directly to excel file on a server into API endpoint and i want to save it/open it

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048825/how-to-upload-file-using-fastapi/70657621#70657621) as well