# Openai api returning 405

Tags: python, fastapi, openai-api

I am creating a central api for translation and i need gpt api to handle the translation. When I run the code i keep geting method not allowed as the response. I tried it with pycharm default api and it worked. I am working with FASTAPI.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import requests

app = FastAPI()
api_key = ""//openai auth key
api_endpoint = "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions"


class TranslationRequest(BaseModel):
    text: str


class TranslationResponse(BaseModel):
    translation: str


class ErrorResponse(BaseModel):
    error: str


@app.post("/translate", response_model=TranslationResponse, responses={500: {"model": ErrorResponse}})
def translate():
    text = "how are you"
    header = {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
    }

    payload = {
        "model": "text-davinci-003",
        "prompt": f"Translate {text} to dutch",
        "max_tokens": 100,
        "temperature": 0.5,
    }
    response = requests.post(api_endpoint, headers=header, json=payload)

    if response.status_code == 405:
        print(response.json()["choices"][0]["text"])
    else:
        print(f"Request failed with status: {str(response.status_code)}")


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello {name}"}
```

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804), when it comes to making HTTP requests inside of FastAPI endpoints.