# KeyError: 'response_data' in FastAPI application

Tags: python, json, rest, python-requests, fastapi

I am building a FastAPI application that receives a message and an image to return an edited image based on the message provided with the image. The problem is the app is returning an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "C:\Users\abu aisha\Documents\whatsappPhotoEditor\main.py", line 63, in reply
    image_url = image_response.json()["response_data"]["result"]["output"][0]
KeyError: 'response_data'
```

Below is the code to the FastAPI application, I have done some research and could not come up with anything tangible, that is why i am seeking the community's help

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, File, UploadFile
import requests
from utils import send_message
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import json

load_dotenv()

app = FastAPI(debug=True)

api_key = os.getenv("MONSTER_API_KEY")
bearer_token = os.getenv("BEARER_TOKEN")
whatsapp_number = os.getenv("TO_NUMBER")

@app.post("/message")
async def reply(file: UploadFile = File(...), prompt: str = Form(...)):
    file.filename = "image.jpg"
    contents = await file.read()

    with open(f"{file.filename}", "wb") as f:
        f.write(contents)

    url = "https://api.monsterapi.ai/apis/add-task"

    payload = {
        "model": "pix2pix",
        "data": {
            "prompt": prompt,
            "negprompt": "",
            "steps": 50,
            "guidance_scale": 12.5,
            "init_image_url": file.filename,
            "image_guidance_scale": 1.5
        }
    }
    headers = {
        'x-api-key': api_key,
        'Authorization': bearer_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
    response.raise_for_status()
    process_id = response.json()["process_id"]

    response_url = "https://api.monsterapi.ai/apis/task-status"
    response_payload = {
        "process_id": process_id
    }
    response_headers = {
        'x-api-key': api_key,
        'Authorization': bearer_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    image_response = requests.request("POST", response_url, headers=response_headers, data=response_payload)

    image_url = image_response.json()["response_data"]["result"]["output"][0]

    send_message(whatsapp_number, image_url)

    return ""
```

This is the contents of `response.json()`

```
{'message': 'Request accepted successfully', 'process_id': 'eee2c49e-083a-11ee-b335-99c647f2e5d3'}
```

This is the content of `image_response.json()`

```
{'message': 'Request processed successfully', 'response_data': {'process_id': 'eee2c49e-083a-11ee-b335-99c647f2e5d3', 'status': 'COMPLETED', 'result': {'output': ['https://processed-model-result.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/eee2c49e-083a-11ee-b335-99c647f2e5d3_0.png']}, 'credit_used': 4, 'overage': 0}}
```

This is the `send_message()` function

```
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

load_dotenv()

account_sid = os.getenv("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID")
auth_token = os.getenv("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN")
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
twilio_number = os.getenv('TWILIO_NUMBER')

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Sending message logic through Twilio Messaging API
def send_message(to_number, media):
    try:
        message = client.messages.create(
            from_=f"whatsapp:{twilio_number}",
            to=f"whatsapp:{to_number}",
            media_url=[media]
            )
        logger.info(f"Message sent to {to_number}: {message.media_url}")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error sending message to {to_number}: {e}")
```

Comment: There is no `response_data` in the request that you send to `https://api.monsterapi.ai/apis/add-task`. please log the response first. see what is in `image_response`

Comment: On a side note, please avoid using the `requests` module within an `async def` endpoint. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to find out as to why not to do that, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) for the proper way of making HTTP requests inside of FastAPI applications.

Comment: I am still having the same issues

Comment: What I noticed is that the requests have a waiting time, how can I handle the waiting time in the fastAPI application

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError` is raised due to a bad dictionary key lookup. In other words, when trying to access a key that isn't in a `dict`.

Testing the `image_response` dictionary you provided in the question, it should work as expected without getting any `KeyError`. Hence, please make sure that `response_data` is in the `dict` every time you receive a JSON response and attempt accessing it. The example below uses the `dict` and the code you provided for extracting the `image_url` from  `response_data`, and demonstrates that should work as expected.

### Example

```py
image_response = {
    "message": "Request processed successfully",
    "response_data": {
        "process_id": "eee2c49e-083a-11ee-b335-99c647f2e5d3",
        "status": "COMPLETED",
        "result": {
            "output": [
                "https://processed-model-result.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/eee2c49e-083a-11ee-b335-99c647f2e5d3_0.png"
            ]
        },
        "credit_used": 4,
        "overage": 0,
    },
}

image_url = image_response["response_data"]["result"]["output"][0]
print(image_url)
```

### Important

You should rather avoid using the `requests` module within an `async def` endpoint. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to find out as to why not to do that, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) on how to properly make HTTP requests inside of a FastAPI application.