# Instagram python request to get access_token

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I want to create instagram authentication using a python request to get an access token

```
router = APIRouter(prefix="/meta/instagram", tags=["instagram"])

SCOPE = 'instagram_graph_user_profile,instagram_graph_user_media'

@router.get("/auth")
async def login(request: Request):
    state = secrets.token_hex(16)
    auth_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize'
    payload = {
        'client_id': config.id_app_ig,
        'redirect_uri': config.redirect_uri_ig,
        'response_type': 'code',
        'state': state,
        'scope': SCOPE
    }
    complete_url = auth_url + urlencode(payload)
    return RedirectResponse(complete_url)

@router.get("/auth2callback")
async def token(code: str):
    token_url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token'
    payload = {
        'client_id': config.id_app_ig,
        'redirect_uri': config.redirect_uri_ig,
        'client_secret': config.secret_app_ig,
        'code': code
    }
    get_access_token = requests.post(token_url, data=payload)
    access_token = get_access_token.json().get("access_token")
    return JSONResponse (access_token)
```

but always error like this:
[image: auth eror]

can somebody help me with this eror

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed adding the `?` sign after `/authorize`. Hence, the URL to get the [Authorization Code](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-access-tokens-and-permissions#step-1--get-authorization) should look like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id...
                                         ^
```

I would highly suggest using `httpx` instead of `requests` to make HTTP requests within a FastAPI `async def` endpoint. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) for more details.